# Win 8 / WP 8: MMVM Framework?

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-8, windows-phone-8

In the past I have used mvvmlight with some degree of success via wpf. I have recently seen Caliburn Micro but I would like to know if anyone has any experience with it.

I see the website for Caliburn Micro and it states it works on WP7 and WPF, what about win8 and wp8?

From what I understand Caliburn Micro takes away a lot the configuration away and goes with convention, this sounds nice, similar approach to asp.net mvc

Can anyone confirm that INavigationService can be used with CM ? Also is it true that no binding exists in CM because the items just work because of convention?

Or should I just continue with the MVVM Light route?

MVVM Light release schedule is a little delayed, anyone know what the release schedule is with CM?

Comment: Anybody used MVVM Light and moved to Caliburn.Micro ?? Was it a good move, or are you intending on moving back?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "MVVM Light release schedule is a little delayed". It works with WinRT just like in WPF.

Comment: What i meant to say is that the release schedule is 1 release per year more or less. I do have experience with mvvmlight so i will take a closer look. thanks.

Comment: You might also be interested in looking at the Okra App Framework (http://okra.codeplex.com) for Windows 8 development. It currently doesn't support Windows Phone, but was designed with Windows 8 in mind so has great support for the Win8 specifics such as search, sharing, settings, etc. - I'm lead developer on the project so feel free to get in touch if you have any queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Caliburn.Micro supports WinRT and WP8 - see http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Working%20with%20WinRT&referringTitle=Documentation for WinRT documentation.

Caliburn.Micro has a convention over configuration approach so it will automatically bind controls on your view with verbs on your view models based on the name of the control. You can configure these conventions or just use explict bindings if you want to override this.

It supports INavigationService, and the last release of Caliburn.Micro was 1.5.1 on March 22nd.

Comment: Thanks, I clicked on the link and it states that "the WINRT version of caliburn.micro is.."  so there are 2 different versions, I only see 1 here http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/releases/view/103870

Comment: Package contains 1 project which builds for diff targets afaik, download and there should be RT binaries

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you take a look at [CaliburnMicroWinRT](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/marker_metro/CaliburnMicroWinRT). It includes some new features for Windows 8:

- Property Binding conventions
- Method Binding conventions
- Coroutines
- Screens and Conductors
- Navigation including Parameter injection
- Windows 8 Share charm integration
- Windows 8 Search charm integration

You can read more about the new changes [here.](http://www.markermetro.com/2012/08/technical/caliburn-micro-for-winrt-mvvm-magic-pixie-dust-for-everyone/)

Many of these changes should have been merged with the official build as well. Take a look at the official NuGet [here](http://nuget.org/packages/Caliburn.Micro).

Comment: Yes looks good but i think i would rather keep with the official release if at all possible.

Comment: Were these were eventually folded into the main branch by Rob?

Comment: I haven't been keeping up to date, but at least parts of the functionality has been merged or ported to the main branch.

Answer (score 0):

You should really read up on the CM codeplex site http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com

It supports `INavigationService`, it supports binding by convention or binding explicitly (though binding by convention is very powerful). It has a good release schedule (there have been two or more releases in the last 6-8 months including a major version). You can completely customise the conventions etc

I use it a lot - though I have not used MVVM Light so I can't comment on how that stacks up.

I can say, however, that CM has a very shallow learning curve and because it is so lightweight it's easy to memorise most of the codebase.

It is also very pluggable - if there is something you don't like you can just swap out a `Func<>` somewhere and replace it with your implementation.